# Android: How do I retrieve problematic data from a specific webpage?

Tags: html, android, vb.net, dom, shdocvw

I have used .NET and ShDocVw for years to grab data off webpages without any issues I couldn't overcome.  This website has me beat though.  It seems like such as easy task to grab the titles and other information off a library search page, but I can't see the data to be able to grab it.  Usually, I just look in the DOM, but the data wasn't there.  I did a view source, but the data wasn't there.  I am so confused.

I am learning Android right now and that is how I would like to solve my problem, but if .NET would be easier...  Right now I will take any help, in any form.

The URL is http://catalog.kcls.org/opac/en-US/skin/kcls/xml/rresult.xml?if=&it=h&bl=&lf=&a=&la=&cl=&d=1&l=1&s=pubdate&sd=desc&adt=ml&tp=&t=bibcn%3ADVD%20FIC%20ON%20ORDER&av=&rt=multi

Answer (score 1):

For this specific website, if you disable javascript in your browser, you will see they give you a link to a plain html search portal

http://catalog.kcls.org/opac/en-US/extras/slimpac/start.html

Comment: Not the answer I was expecting, but exactly an answer that I can use.  Thank you so much, Chris.  I followed the new link and saw my data.  Yipee!!!!